# Alert Dialog showing again after Screen On

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, screen-off

i have an other problem. I have an Alert Dialog shown on onCreate. The problem is that if i turn screen off and back on the dialog will appear again, so i have two dialog with the same content after screen unlock. How can i fix this to not show the dialog is allready showing?

Thanks!

Comment: are you usuing DialogFragment ?

Comment: no, but i fixed it right now by using an integer that changes value on alert.show(); if it is 1 the dialog will not show up :D

Comment: Ok :D good luck. please answer your question for other that may have this issue

Answer (score -1):

FAST FIX:

```
// your class starts here
int x=0;
// your onCreate starts here
if(x==0){ 
  alert.show();
  x=1;
}
```

Alert Dialog Dismiss Code

```
alert.dismiss();
x=0;
```

And it will work